# Assistance with join using a where clause and duplicates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having some difficulty with writing an accurate view.

I have 2 tables that I am looking to join on different databases.

Table 1 (in database 1) contains 3 columns:

- Purchase_date
- Item_id
- Quantity_purchased

Table 2 (in database 2) contains 3 columns:

- Item_id
- Price_effective_date
- Price

I am trying to determine the price of the item at the purchase date, which is a challenge since the item prices change on price effective dates.  Accordingly, table 2 will have multiple instances of the same item_id, but with different prices and price effective dates.

My current code is:

```sql
select tb1.*,  
tb2.price x tb1.quantity_purchased as total_price 


from "Database2"."schema"."Table1" tb1 

left join (select item_id, 
    price
  from "Database2"."Schema"."Table2"
  
  ) tb2

on tb1.item_id = tb2.item_id
where tb2.price_effective_date <= tb1.purchase_date
```

I want to limit my results to the price at the most recent price_effective_date that is just before the purchase_date.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Which implementation of SQL is this? Where is Table2's 5th column?

Comment: We use snowflake so whatever that is.  The 5 columns were a typo.  Actually is 4.  Just fixed

Comment: So you should [edit] to tag the relevant Snowflake product(s). I've made an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really Snowflake specific, and luckily it can be addressed with a pretty common pattern in SQL queries.

Let's prepare some data (btw, for the future, it's best to provide the exact setup like this in your questions, it helps investigations tremendously):

```
create or replace table tb1(purchase_date date, item_id int, quantity int);
insert into tb1 values
  ('2020-01-01', 101, 1),
  ('2020-06-30', 101, 1),
  ('2020-07-01', 101, 1),
  ('2020-12-31', 101, 1),
  ('2021-01-01', 101, 1),
  ('2020-01-01', 102, 1),
  ('2020-06-30', 102, 1),
  ('2020-07-01', 102, 1),
  ('2020-12-31', 102, 1),
  ('2021-01-01', 102, 1);
  
create or replace table tb2(item_id int, effective_date date, price decimal);
insert into tb2 values
  (101, '2020-01-01', 10),
  (101, '2021-01-01', 11),
  (102, '2020-01-01', 20),
  (102, '2020-07-01', 18),
  (102, '2021-01-01', 22);
```

Now, what you want is to join records from `tb1` and `tb2` on `item_id`, but only use the records from `tb2` where `effective_date` is the *largest* of all the values of `effective_date` for that item that are before `purchase_date`. Correct? If you phrase it like this, the SQL writes itself almost:

```
select tb1.*, tb2.effective_date, tb2.price
from tb1 join tb2 on tb1.item_id = tb2.item_id
where tb2.effective_date = (
  select max(effective_date) 
  from tb2 sub 
  where sub.effective_date <= tb1.purchase_date 
  and sub.item_id = tb1.item_id
)
order by tb1.item_id, purchase_date;
```

The result is hopefully what you want:

| PURCHASE_DATE | ITEM_ID | QUANTITY | EFFECTIVE_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 101 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 10 |
| 2020-12-31 | 101 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | 101 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 11 |
| 2020-01-01 | 102 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 20 |
| 2020-06-30 | 102 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 20 |
| 2020-07-01 | 102 | 1 | 2020-07-01 | 18 |
| 2020-12-31 | 102 | 1 | 2020-07-01 | 18 |
| 2021-01-01 | 102 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 22 |

Note, this query will not handle wrong data, e.g. purchases with no matching items and effective dates.

### EDIT: Handling missing effective_dates

To handle cases where there are no effective dates matching the purchase date, you can identify the "missing" purchases, and then add the smallest existing effective_date for these items, e.g. (we add a new item, value `103` to the existing table to showcase this):

```
insert into tb1 values
  ('2020-06-01', 103, 11),
  ('2020-08-01', 103, 12);
insert into tb2 values
 (103, '2020-07-01', 30);

with missing as (
  select * from tb1 where not exists (
    select * from tb2 
    where tb2.effective_date <= tb1.purchase_date 
      and tb2.item_id = tb1.item_id)
)
select m.item_id, m.purchase_date, m.quantity, 
  (select min(effective_date) from tb2 where tb2.item_id = m.item_id) best_date
from missing m;
```

You can take this query and UNION ALL it with the original query.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. You hit the nail on the head for what I'm trying to accomplish. Your code makes sense. However, after implementing your code, I am still getting more results than total items. For instance, I have 102,837 orders and when I run the code, I get 110,908 results.  Any additional advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You really need to provide a reproducible example along the lines of what I did. Saying "I get 110,908 results" doesn't mean anything without the context.

Comment: I figured out the issue, which is unrelated to the formula, but with an issue in the raw data.  Thank you.  As a follow-up that deals with this issue, we found that in some rare cases, the purchase date precedes the effective_date.  In that scenario, we would want to select the closest date to the after purchase date. How would you recommend modifying the query to account for this contingency?

Comment: Added one way to handle that, see the bottom of the answer.

Comment: This latter query is yielding a compilation error due to m.effective_date as an invalid identifier.  I might be doing this wrong, but I directly copy and pasted your code and then filled in the correct table names and column names.  I did not combine this with the previous code

Comment: Please double check everything. I did, and it works for me. Note that `m_effective_date` does not appear in my query, so I have no idea what you're really running.